# In App Purchase Build Rejection issue in Itunesconnect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have submitted iOS App to app store for review process. This app contains In App Purchase. This App is rejected from Apple and below is the message i have received :

" We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.

We are unable to complete the review of your app because one or more of your in-app purchase products have not been submitted for review.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please be sure to take action and submit your in-app purchases and upload a new binary in iTunes Connect. Learn more about how to offer in-app purchases in iTunes Connect Developer Help.

Once you've submitted your in-app purchases and uploaded a new binary, we can proceed with your review."

does it mean i have to upload new binary ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to upload new binary, just add inapp purchases in application details page, while app status is "Prepare for Submission". Than you can submit same (rejected) build again and inapp purchases will be reviewed.